# Running reverseGeocodeLocation function create exception in SwiftPlay or return nothing

Tags: swift, mapkit, core-location

I tried to run the code provided in the answer from this post ([Swift - Generate an Address Format from Reverse Geocoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358423/swift-generate-an-address-format-from-reverse-geocoding)) to get the address information from the latitude and longitude information. When I try to run this in Swift Playground (the standalone one from App Store and the one included with Xcode 14), it doesn't seem to do anything at first run.  However, after drilling into it there seems to be a bad exception of some sort.

```swift
import CoreLocation

func getAddressFromLatLon(pdblLatitude: String, withLongitude pdblLongitude: String) {
    var center : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    let lat: Double = Double("\(pdblLatitude)")!
    //21.228124
    let lon: Double = Double("\(pdblLongitude)")!
    //72.833770
    let ceo: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
    center.latitude = lat
    center.longitude = lon
    
    let loc: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)
    
    
    ceo.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
        
        if pm.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks![0]
            print(pm.country)
            print(pm.locality)
            print(pm.subLocality)
            print(pm.thoroughfare)
            print(pm.postalCode)
            print(pm.subThoroughfare)
            var addressString : String = ""
            if pm.subLocality != nil {
                addressString = addressString + pm.subLocality! + ", "
            }
            if pm.thoroughfare != nil {
                addressString = addressString + pm.thoroughfare! + ", "
            }
            if pm.locality != nil {
                addressString = addressString + pm.locality! + ", "
            }
            if pm.country != nil {
                addressString = addressString + pm.country! + ", "
            }
            if pm.postalCode != nil {
                addressString = addressString + pm.postalCode! + " "
            }
            
            print(addressString)
        }
    })
}

getAddressFromLatLon(pdblLatitude: "42.48001070918", withLongitude: "-76.4511703657")
```

Looking at the error it says:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
> The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

I'm not following what's going on. If I use this code in a SwiftUI project, I also get bad exception that halts the program. It seems like an issue with the async function `reverseGeocodeLocation`, but I'm not sure why the error isn't caught even though it should be handling it in the closures.

I also tried using `import MapKit` instead of `import Location`.  With MapKit, it doesn't error out but the code seems to do nothing.  The coordinate should have come up as Lansing, NY. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around with the code I found the cause of the error. It is any attempt to create an instance of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. Very strange. Since you can easily create the `CLLocation` instance directly from the `lat` and `lon` values you can avoid the error.

Here's a vastly cleaned up version of your code. This code eliminates all forced unwraps. The following runs just fine in an Xcode 14.1 playground.

Besides all of the code cleanup, it's the removal of using `CLLocationCoordinate2D` that resolved the main issue.

```
import CoreLocation

func getAddressFromLatLon(pdblLatitude: String, withLongitude pdblLongitude: String) {
    guard let lat = Double(pdblLatitude),
          let lon = Double(pdblLongitude) else { return }

    let loc = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    let ceo = CLGeocoder()

    ceo.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        if let error {
            print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error)")
        } else if let placemarks, let pm = placemarks.first {
            var addressString = ""
            if let val = pm.subLocality {
                addressString += val + ", "
            }
            if let val = pm.thoroughfare {
                addressString += val + ", "
            }
            if let val = pm.locality {
                addressString += val + ", "
            }
            if let val = pm.country {
                addressString += val + ", "
            }
            if let val = pm.postalCode {
                addressString += val + " "
            }

            print(addressString)
        }
    })
}

getAddressFromLatLon(pdblLatitude: "42.48001070918", withLongitude: "-76.4511703657")
```

---

Even if you create a brand new iOS playground in Xcode 14.1 and enter just the following code it will crash the playground:

```
import CoreLocation

print("Before")
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
print("After")
```

Output:

> Before
> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: I just submitted a bug report to Apple about this issue.

Comment: Thank you for finding this bug.  I have noticed that Apple has created many bugs in the native framework that used to work in the past as they updating stuff at a break neck speed.  I started developing on macOS on January 1st this year and it's only been 11 months but I went from Xcode 12 to Xcode 14 and macOS 11 to 13.  Is this a new norm for Apple?

Comment: I accepted the solution since you pointed me to the correct solution.  The code you provided has issue with the unwrapping though.  I get "Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer" in the if let error ... section

Comment: @Patratacus Odd, I get no such issue when I run this exact code in a Playground created using Xcode 14.1 while running under macOS 12.6. Apple puts out one major new release of macOS, iOS, and Xcode each year in the Fall. This year was Xcode 14, macOS 13, and iOS 16. Last year was Xcode 13, macOS 12, and iOS 15. They have followed that pattern for at least a decade.

Comment: I checked and looks like it's OK in my Xcode 14.0 Playground as well, but the problem seems to be with the standalone Playgrounds version 4.1 (1676.15).  Maybe something is different with the standalone Playground.